# How to find dimension of a nested tuple?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple that looks like this

```
  array=(1,2,3,4)
  lenM = numpy.shape(array)
  print lenM
  (4,)

  if not lenM[1]:
       "Code"
```

Now how do I automate the my code to find if the tuple is one dimensional or two dimensional?

Comment: There's a bit of confusion here between tuples and arrays that can be constructed from them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `numpy.ndim` for this:

```
In [4]: np.ndim((1,2,3,4))
Out[4]: 1
In [5]: np.ndim(((1,2),(3,4)))
Out[5]: 2
```

Answer (score 10):

```
array=(1,2,3,4)
lenM = numpy.shape(array)
print lenM
(4,)

if len(lenM) == 1:
    "1 dimensional code"
elif len(lenM) == 2:
    "2 dimensional code"
```

len(lenM) will tell you if there is more than one dimension in array. If len(lenM) is 1, there's only one dimension. if array has more than one dimension, lenM will have more than one element.

Comment: What if I don't know how "a" looks like? should I use len() or np.shape()?